# Structure element values being overwritten during execution

Tags: c, gcc, data-structures

Hopefully I am explaining this correctly, but I am running into an odd problem with a structure that is in a program I am working on. In short, I have two structures setup as follows:

**ParentStructure.h**

```
#include "ChildStructure.h"

struct ParentStructure {
    struct ChildStructure A;
    struct ChildStructure B;
    struct ChildStructure C;
    struct ChildStructure D;
};
```

**ChildStructure.h**

```
struct ChildStructure {   
    short A;
    short B;
};
```

The problem that I am encountering is that one of the variables in the `ParentStructure` (i.e. `ParentSturcutre.D`) has the values `D.A` and `D.B` which are being overwritten during the execution of the program. It appears to me to be due to something with how the structure is designed as when two of the values in the child structure (i.e. `A.A` and `A.B`) are the same, things operate correctly; however, when they are different the `D.A` and `D.B` values are reverted back to their original values when the program executes after a change to `D.A` or `D.B`.

In terms of how the functions are being called, the overall flow is as follows:

**main.c**

```
#define WorkingDefaultAA 10 /* Program executes correctly */
#define WorkingDefaultAB 10

#define NonWorkingDefaultAA 10 /* Program does not execute correctly */
#define NonWorkingDefaultAB  8

struct ParentStructure *data;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /* Set the default values for the data */
    while (true) {
        FunctionA(data);
    }
}
```

**ProcessData.c**

```
void FunctionA(struct ParentStructure *data) {
    /* Use data */
    FunctionB(data);
}

void FunctionB(struct ParentStructure *data) {
    data->D.A = 1;
    data->D.B = 1;    
}
```

Any ideas as to what might be going on?

Comment: Use your debugger's support for data breakpoints.

Comment: Not without seeing (a) the code in question (b) the definition of `(struct ChildStructure)`.

Comment: Does `ParentStructure.h` include `ChildStructure.h` at the top?

Comment: @Hans Passant - The only debugger I have right now is gdb and sadly I'm not too well versed on how to use it yet. Slowly going through things, but it might be a fairly obvious problem for someone. :)

Comment: @geekosaur - I've added some psudo-c to give a rough idea as to what is going on.

Comment: @Null Set - It does indeed, everything compiles and executes correctly, the only issues arise when `A.A` and `A.B` are different values.

Comment: Run your code in gdb and put a watchpoint on the variable that is "reverting", to see exactly which lines of code are modifying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a debugger such as gdb to find out which lines of code are modifying the variable that seems to be reverting.

In gdb, you can set a watchpoint on an expression, which will pause the execution of the program everytime the value of that expression changes. You can then look at the stack trace to see what line of code just executed.

To use gdb effectively, you will need to compile your code with debug symbols. This is the `-g` flag in gcc. Load your program into the debugger with `gdb my_buggy_executable`.

The simplest way to set a watchpoint is to first put a breakpoint in the scope where the variable in question is defined. Suppose your main.c looked like this:

```
#include "ParentStructure.h"
#include "functions.h"

int main(){
    ParentStructure parent;
    parent.A.A = 0;
    parent.B.A = 0;
    parent.C.A = 0;
    parent.D.A = 0;
    parent.A.B = 0;
    parent.B.B = 0;
    parent.C.B = 0;
    parent.D.B = 0;

    functionA(&parent);

    return 0;
}
```

You would then set a breakpoint at line 6 in main.c with the command `break main.c:6`, and then start the program with the command `run`. The execution will pause before line 6 is executed. Now, you would set a watchpoint with the command `watch parent.D.A`. Resume execution with the command `continue`. Now the execution will pause every time parent.D.A is changed. This should show you which lines of code are changing your variable.

Comment: Going with this as the answer as the problem ended up being one of the variables in the structure was being updated unexpectedly during program execution due to a bug in the algorithm. `gdb` ended up being one of the routes used to figure out where the bug was at.

Answer (score 3):

*Edit:   the code fragments below no longer apply as the question changed several times.*

---

That it compiles is surprising, unless there's a forward reference or other type information for `ChildStructure` somewhere.  A pure forward reference should not compile, either, as there's no size information available to the compiler to allocate the correct amount of space for `ParentStructure` without it.

```
struct ChildStructure {   
    int A;
    int B;
};

struct ParentStructure {
    struct ChildStructure A;
    struct ChildStructure B;
    struct ChildStructure C;
    struct ChildStructure D;
};
```

This code compiles.

Is it possible that you are passing the structures to functions "by value" instead of "by reference"?  If you are passing them by reference, then is it possible the compiler is seeing two different definitions of the types `ParentStructure` or `ChildStructure`, and therefore making potential data-hash of your program's execution?

The behavior you are seeing would be immediately explained by passing the structures "by value" to a function to operate upon.

```
void ChangeAB( ChildStructure child ) {
    child.A = 3;
    child.B = 4;
}

void ChangeABByReference( ChildStructure& child ) {
    child.A = 3;
    child.B = 4;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ParentStructure parent;
    parent.A.A = 0;
    parent.A.B = 2;
    ChangeAB(parent.A);
    // check values after returning from ChangeAB()
    ChangeABByReference(parent.A);
    // check values after returning - this time they should stick.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the question to more accurately the setup of the program. I've checked the functions and they are all passing by reference (i.e. `struct ParentStructure *data`).

Comment: I wonder if the forward declaration of `ChildStructure` inadvertantly allows the compiler to think it is a empty structure.  ala:  `struct ChildStructure {};`

Comment: @Andy Finkenstadt - If that were the case wouldn't the program as a whole not work as all of the elements are being used?

Comment: It depends.  There's something called the "One Definition Rule" which permits the linker to arbitrarily select code-function points between object files that match signatures, on an assumption that if it has seen one, it has seen them all.  Therefore, if the linker finds one definition for a code point in one object file, and another in another, the linker is allowed to pick whichever one is most convenient to it.

Comment: And, only you can answer whether at all times that `ChildStructure`s declaration needs to be fully known whether it shares that same declaration.

Comment: @Andy Finkenstadt - That make sense, but I would be surprised if that was the case in regards to the program as all of the values are being accessed during the program execution (the `ChildStrucure` is coordinate data) so it would likely have a segfault the first time the element of an empty structure was accessed.

Comment: @Andy Finkenstadt - Correct, the `ChildStructure` isn't being forward referenced (that's being used for the functions) but just included.

Comment: @Rob Z: It's a bit confusing when you change your code every time someone asks a question. Do you think you could post the actual code?

Comment: @Null Set - The code should be pretty much in line with what is in the code-base, but unfortunately I can't post the actual code.

Comment: @Rob Z: Can you make a separate program which you can compile and run which reproduces this behavior, and then post *that* code?

Comment: @Null Set - Likely not in a timely fashion (maybe sometime tomorrow) but one thing I did notice while working on the code is that the issue only occurs if `data->A.A` and `data->A.B` are different values. If they are the same, or are set to sync with each other, then the program executes as expected, but if they are different values then the program fails to execute as expected (i.e. `data->D.A` will be equal to one on one cycle and then equal to the previous value on the next cycle without any calls being made to set the value).

Comment: As we now know, there was a bug somewhere else entirely, and the use of the debugger helped.  Glad to have helped point out that the code fragment was not reflective of the entire problem.